# Get row ID from kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to get the 'ObjectID' from a selected row in a kendo grid, but currently it's not working.

```
<div class="clearfix">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<M20_AEK.Models.ContractSettlement>()
                    .Name("ContractSettlementGrid")
                    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
                    .Pageable(pageable => pageable.Input(true).Numeric(false))
                    .Scrollable()
                    .Selectable()
                    .Sortable()
                    .Filterable()
                    .ColumnMenu()
                    .Groupable()
                    .Selectable()
                    .Columns(columns =>
                    {
                        columns.Bound(c => c.ObjectID).Title("ID").Hidden();
                        columns.Bound(c => c.OPERATOR_OBJECTID).Title("Operator").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Year).Title("Year").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.Month).Title("Month").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.SETTLEMENT_OBJECTID).Title("Settlement").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.TECHNOLOGY_OBJECTID).Title("Technology").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.UPLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID).Title("Upload").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.DOWNLOAD_SPEED_CLASS_OBJECTID).Title("Download").Width("100px");
                        columns.Bound(c => c.ObjectID)
                            .Title("Edit")
                            .Filterable(false)
                            .ClientTemplate("<a onclick=\"showDetails(this,'#= ObjectID#')\" href='\\#'>Edit</a>");
                        columns.Command(command => { command.Edit(); command.Destroy(); }).Width(172);
                    })
                    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                    .Ajax()
                    .PageSize(20)
                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                    .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.ObjectID))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("LoadSettlementContracts_Read", "SettlementContract"))
                    .Update(update => update.Action("Save", "SettlementContract"))
                    .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "SettlementContract"))
                    )
        )
    </div>

function showDetails(ObjectID) {
       alert(ObjectID);
    }
```

I also tried something like this, as I have found some possible solutions on forums.

```
function showDetails() {
        var grid = $("#ContractSettlementGrid").data("kendoGrid");
        var selectedRow = grid.select();
        var index = selectedRow();
        console.log(index);
        //this does not work
    }
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close to having it work!

You shouldn't need to use a client template for your button (unless there is other code you didn't share). You can change it to:

```
columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Edit").Click("showDetails"));
```

And make the showDetails function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDetails(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        //do whatever you need with the dataItem here
        console.log(dataItem.ObjectID);
    }
</script>
```

Additional info here: https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-core/grid/custom-command

Comment: thanks a bunch, that did the trick. I am interning straight out of college at a company and they use a paid Telerik /Kendo license and it's causing more issues than it's actually helping, thank you sooo much!

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. While they can take some time to get familiar with, the Telerik/Kendo controls (like other similar libraries) can end up saving hundreds if not thousands of hours of effort when you need that type of data management or editor functionality

Answer (score 0):

just use something like this in your grid:

columns.Command(command => command.Custom("Delete").Click("DeleteProduct"));

and then in your jquery:

```
var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
var selectedItem = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
var Id =  selectedItem.Id;
```